# How to find a SQL Server 2008 instance, including default instance

Tags: sql-server, find, default, instance

I am creating a Windows form application that uses SQL Server 2008. In the setup project that I have I check for and install SQL Server 2008 if necessary on the target machine. What I need is a way to get a SQL Server 2008 - and ONLY 2008 - instance name.

Right now I am using the `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers` function and checking the versions returned, but what I have found is that it does not display the default instance. This is problematic for me because if this program is being run after my installer setup SQL Server 2008 on the target machine, there are no named instances available - only the default instance.

I don't want to just blindly check and see if the traditional `MSSQLSERVER` default instance works for two reasons:

1. It could be the default instance left over from a SQL Server 2008 install, which won't be able to access the DB used by my application. Skipping it and then checking for other named instances would most likely return me nothing.
2. It could also be the default instance from a newer version of SQL Server 2012. While this instance would be able to access my DB, my experience is that it then "upgrades" the DB to the new SQL Server version, and earlier versions won't be able to access it. Since my application is intended to work with SQL Server 2008, this presents me with some problems.

SO I need to use any SQL Server 2008 named instance, or a default instance IF it is 2008.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I thought I had a solution with using SqlDataSourceEnumerator. By using the GetDataSources() method of the Instance member of this, it looks like Default instances show up, but only the name of the machine that default instanc eis running on is given. No version informaiton is provided, which creates a problem for me.

Comment: Take a look to my answer, try it!

Answer (score 2):

Use should use the class `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` of the `System.Data.Sql` namespace (assembly `System.Data.dll`), this way:

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator sdsEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;

DataTable sqlServerInstances = sdsEnumerator.GetDataSources();
```

These class will not require to have Sql Server installed, but can retrieve informations about any Sql Server instance. Remind this:

"

Due to the nature of the mechanism used by SqlDataSourceEnumerator to locate data sources on a network, the method will not always return a complete list of the available servers, and the list might not be the same on every call. If you plan to use this function to let users select a server from a list, make sure that you always also supply an option to type in a name that is not in the list, in case the server enumeration does not return all the available servers. In addition, this method may take a significant amount of time to execute, so be careful about calling it when performance is critical.

"

The method `GetDataSource` is what you need: [here the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), returns a `DataTable` with all the informations you need:

**ServerName**
Name of the server.

**InstanceName**
Name of the server instance. Blank if the server is running as the default instance.

**IsClustered**
Indicates whether the server is part of a cluster.

**Version**
Version of the server (8.00.x for SQL Server 2000, and 9.00.x for SQL Server 2005, 10.00.x for SQL Server 2008, 10.50.x for SQL Server 2008 R2 and 11.00.x for SQL Server 2012).

You can find the full reference of the class `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).